# What does "intuite from" mean in this content?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> Aristotle correctly **intuited from** this curved shadow that the Earth is curvy all around

What does this sentence structure *intuit from* mean in this content?

Regards!

Comment: Could you please look up the words *intuit* and *from*? After you've done that, please tell us how none of the definitions within match the given context. The online dictionaries provided [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english#739) might help you.

Comment: An intuition is a conclusion your brain has  reached but you're unable to show step by step how your brain reached that conclusion. The verb **intuit** means to reach such a conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do dictionaries say about its meaning? The Collins English Dictionary defines the verb [**intuit**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/intuit) like this:

> If you intuit something, you guess what it is on the basis of your intuition or feelings, rather than on the basis of knowledge.

So, apparently Aristotle used his intuition rather than concrete scientific knowledge (science in general was not very well developed back then) to arrive at the idea that the Earth was actually round rather than flat. He got that intuition from the fact that the shadows that objects cast looked curvy. So, that's where he intuited that idea from.

Another example:

> Even though I did not know the correct answers to most of the questions on the test, I was still able to **intuit** them **from** my limited knowledge which helped me get an A!

Comment: I still didn't get what it meant. There's the preposition ''from'' if you haven't seen yet. Therefore, I'm asking what ''intuit from'' means in that content.

Answer (score 1):

Aristotle "intuited" (sensed or guessed) that the Earth was round. The observable fact he used to make this guess was curved shadows. (It was the fact he guessed "from.")

This definition of from is

> —used as a function word to indicate the source, cause, agent, or basis

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from)